# Nilpotent binary matrices over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, nilpotence

I am studying on nilpotent matrices over finite fields. By definition a square matrix $A$ is $p$-nilpotent if a power of $A$ modulo $p$ is the zero matrix. For example. Let $J_2$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix of ones. Then $J_2$ is 2-nilpotent. Now, if we consider a $p\times p$ matrix $A$ in which entries are from the set $\{0,1\}$ ($A$ is usually called binary or $(0,1)$-matrix) and $A$ is $p$-nilpotent so that the entries all the main diagonal of $A$ are all ones. Does any one has any idea about the form of matrix $A$? I believe that in this case $A$ should be equal to the all ones matrix.

Comment: Any triangular matrix with zeros on the diagonal is nilpotent.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to include here another condition for $A$ that the entries all the main diagonal are all ones. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If $p$ is even, then $A$ need not be the all-ones matrix.  For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1}
$$
is nilpotent over $\Bbb F_2$ and has $1$s on the diagonal

Comment: I need that condition, because I am considering the directed graph in which every vertex has a loop. As we know, there is a theorem stating that a directed graph is acyclic iff the adjacency matrix is nilpotent. But I haven't seen any version of that theorem for finite fields.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That example is for the case of $4\times 4$ matrix. If the matrix is $p\times p$, it should be the all ones matrix.

Comment: @Hieu is $p$ supposed to be prime?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is prime.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to use the Perron-Frobenius theorem.  This states our $\{0,1\}$ is interpreted as a real matrix, it must have a non-negative eigenvector associated with its spectral radius

Comment: Also, if $x$ is such an eigenvector, and if $\hat x$ is $x$ with $0$s replaced with $1$s, then
$$
\operatorname{diag}^{-1}(\hat x)A\operatorname{diag}(\hat x)
$$
is a non-negative matrix with constant row sums equal to $\rho(A)$

Comment: We have a quite powerful theorem which states that *Given a graph, then the associated matrix A is primitive if and only if the graph is strongly connected and has two cycles of relatively prime lengths.[1](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/1180912pf.pdf)*  Although with this theorem you can not prove that a matrix is primitive over finite field, you can detriment that a matrix is non-primitive or not. In the other words, this theorem for finite field is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. it is a question if we may adapt the theorem for $F_p$, likes if the graph has at least one cycle of length 1 then the number of cycles of length $p$ in the graphs is a multiple of $p$ iff the adjacency matrix is $p$-nilpotent.

Comment: If we consider $A$ as a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, we have that the matrix $A$ is non-negative. If $A$ is also irreducible then $A$ is primitive by the theorem.